# Java 16 pattern matching problem with Switch in Intellij IDEA 2020.3.3 (Expression expected)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-16, java-sealed-type

As we know Java 16 brings with a new features like Records, sealed interfaces and classes, and also pattern matching.

Today I wanted use them in my training project. However, I ran into a problem, maybe I don't understand something.

So situation looks like in the given code which represents my Intellij Idea project:
I have packages: client and order
Client class is a sealed interface with three implementation: Regular, Vip and SuperVip:

```
package com.example.records.domain.client;
public sealed interface Client permits Client.Regular, Client.SuperVip, Client.Vip {
        
            Limit currentLimit();
        
            record Regular() implements Client {
        
                @Override
                public Client.Limit currentLimit() {
                    return Client.Limit.of((short) 10);
                }
            }
        
        
            record Vip() implements Client {
        
                @Override
                public Client.Limit currentLimit() {
                    return Client.Limit.of((short) 20);
                }
            }
        
            record SuperVip() implements Client {
        
                @Override
                public Client.Limit currentLimit() {
                    return Client.Limit.of((short) 100);
                }
            }
        
        
            record Limit(short value) {
                public Limit {
                    if (value < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values below 0 not allowed!");
                }
        
                static Limit of(short value) {
                    return new Limit(value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Order class is a simple aggregate knows from DDD:
But there is a problem with switch statement:

```
package com.example.records.domain.order;

import com.example.records.domain.OrderId;
import com.example.records.domain.client.Client;
import com.example.records.domain.client.Client.*;
import com.example.records.shared.Money;
import com.example.records.shared.Result;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Order() {
    private final OrderId orderId;
    private final Client client;
    private final LinesItems linesItems = LinesItems.empty();

    Order(OrderId orderId, Client client) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Result add(LineItem lineItem) {
       return switch (client) {
            case Regular r -> addAnItemIfTheLimitIsNotExceeded(r.);
            case Vip v -> addAnItemIfTheLimitIsNotExceeded(v.);
            case SuperVip sv -> addAnItemIfTheLimitIsNotExceeded(sv.);
        };
    }

    private Result addAnItemIfTheLimitIsNotExceeded(Limit limit) {
        // TODO need impl
        return Result.OK;
    }


    private static class LinesItems {
        private final List<LineItem> lines = new LinkedList<>();

        private LinesItems() {}

        void add(LineItem lineItem) {
            this.lines.add(lineItem);
        }

        Money cost() {
            return lines.stream().map(LineItem::cost).reduce(Money.ZERO, Money::add);
        }

        static LinesItems empty() {
            return new LinesItems();
        }
    }
}

record LineItem(Money cost) {}
```

Other classes:

```
package com.example.records.domain;

public record OrderId(String value) {

    public OrderId {
        validate();
    }

    private void validate() {
        if (value == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null value not allowed!");
        if (value.isBlank())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Blank value not allowed!");
    }
}
package com.example.records.shared;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public record Money(BigDecimal value) {

    public static final Money ZERO = new Money(new BigDecimal("0.00"));

    public Money add(Money money) {
        return new Money(this.value.add(money.value));
    }
}
package com.example.records.shared;

public sealed interface Result {

    Success OK = new Success();

    record Success() implements Result{}
    record Failure(String message) implements Result {}
}
```

I'm getting "(Expression expected)"
Where did I go wrong?
(Experimental features is enabled, I've installed Java 16 open jdk)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sharing the code instead of images is a much better way to ask and let others attempt to reproduce. Besides readability!

Comment: he's sharing code as image to show us the IDE error! So it is good! Anyway are you sure that experimental featurel are selected in project structure -> project tab? Can you post a screenshot of that tab?

Comment: Thank for yours comment I've added code and screenshots of ide settings.

Comment: What you are expecting seems to be something planned for the future. Could you link the references which says that this kind of pattern matching is already a part of Java-16?

Answer (score 14):

Type patterns in `instanceof` are a final (non-preview) feature in Java 16.  However, type patterns in `switch` are not yet in Java 16; they are expected to arrive soon.

Answer (score 5):

The owner of [jeps 394](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394) Gavin Bierman has already submitted a JEP for that feature.

[Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213076)

It has not yet been targeted to a release.

**Edit**: Just a quick update here. This feature has been proposed to be included in **JDK 17**. It is the [JEP 406 here](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/17/)